# Can I use GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso to set a permission option on an Outlook Email?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying write an Outlook Add-In that would create an email, set a specific permission from the Permission dropdown in Outlook to encrypt the email, and then sent out the email. The encrypt permission come from an Information Rights Management template. To access the specific permission. I am trying to using `mailItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso`

I am trying to determine:

1. Is this the best way to access the encrypt option from the permission drop down in Outlook?
2. If so, which Mso am I to use in `mailItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso`?

I've tried `mailItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PermissionRestrictMenu")`, which give me the error
[Message: Value does not fall within expected range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQvf5.png)

and `mailItem.GetInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PermissionRestrict")` which selects the default permission, which is not the option I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`. There is no menus in the list of supported UI controls.

As a possible workaround you may use any low-level API exploring tool such as `MFCMAPI` or `OutlookSpy` for checking properties set after changes made in the Outlook UI.

Another workaround is to use [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) API which is a Component Object Model (COM)-based technology that improves the way accessibility aids work with applications running on Microsoft Windows. It provides dynamic-link libraries that are incorporated into the operating system as well as a COM interface and API elements that provide reliable methods for exposing information about UI elements.